# symfony 3 + FosUserBundle firewalled pages do not display login form

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am making a site with Symfony3 and there is expected need for some pages to be firewall-ed. For user management i am using FosUserBundle ~2.0@dev.

Logging in and out works (so it seems to me that FosUserBundle is configured correctly).

I am expecting that login form is to be shown if page is firewalled.

BUT, these URLs does not respect firewall and display their content for anonymous users...

- localhost:8000/en/admin
- localhost:8000/en/admin/delete-tev
- localhost:8000/en/admin/import-tev
- localhost:8000/en/admin/click-list

here is my security.yml configuration:

```
security:

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|img|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider:             fos_userbundle
                login_path:           fos_user_security_login
                check_path:           fos_user_security_check
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: goods_list_exclusive

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/click_list, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin/import_tev, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin/delete_tev, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

here is my routing:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

# redirecting home
homepage:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: goods_list_exclusive
        permanent: true

# redirecting home
homepage_lv:
    path: /lv/
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: goods_list_exclusive
        permanent: true

# redirecting home
homepage_en:
    path: /en/
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: goods_list_exclusive
        permanent: true

# redirecting home
homepage_ru:
    path: /ru/
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: goods_list_exclusive
        permanent: true

goods_list_exclusive:
    path:     /{_locale}/goods-list-exclusive
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Goods:goodsListExclusive }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

goods_list_new:
    path:     /{_locale}/goods-list-new
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Goods:goodsListNew }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

goods_show:
    path:     /{_locale}/goods-show/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Goods:goodsShow }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

goods_external_link:
    path:     /{_locale}/goods-external-link/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Goods:goodsExternalLink }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

admin_import_tev:
    path:     /{_locale}/admin/import-tev
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Import:importTev }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

admin_delete_tev:
    path:     /{_locale}/admin/delete-tev
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Delete:deleteTev }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

admin_click_list:
    path:     /{_locale}/admin/click-list
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Click:clickList }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

admin:
    path:     /{_locale}/admin
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:admin }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patterns in your access control rules that restrict access for anonymous users all start with `/admin` while the URL path starts with the locale. Thus you should update the patterns to match the actual path. For example, you can have something like this (it assumes that there always is a two-letter locale, but you can adapt it to your needs):

```
access_control:
    # ...
    - { path: '^/[a-z]{2}/admin/click_list', role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: '^/[a-z]{2}/admin/import_tev', role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: '^/[a-z]{2}/admin/delete_tev', role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: '^/[a-z]{2}/admin/', role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Tried it and it states there are 3 problems - but really there is problem with YML - it seems "{" and "}" is not allowed.

So i tried to put second "[a-z]" instead of "{2}" and it works now.
Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah sorry, the pattern indeed needs to be quoted properly then. I updated my answer accordingly.